# How to properly configure a custom facet in Sitecore 9.1

Tags: xdb, xconnect, contact-facets

I have been trying the Sitecore samples to define a `custom facet`, and it all works if I do it outside from Sitecore. But when I want Sitecore to track the contacts and add data to the custom facet, I get the following error:

```
18452 23:26:42 ERROR Cannot create tracker.
Exception: System.ArgumentException
Message: The specified type is not a valid facet type.
Parameter name: facetType
Source: Sitecore.Analytics.Model
    at Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework.ModelFactory.CreateFacet(Type facetType)
    at Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework.Faceted.AddFacet(String name, Type type)
```

I have set up the facet as:

```
[Serializable]
[FacetKey(DefaultFacetKey)]
public class MemberProfile : Facet
{
    public const string DefaultFacetKey = "MemberProfile";

    public MemberProfile()
    {        }

    public int Zone
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
//OTHER PROPERTIES HERE
}
```

This is my model:

```
public class MemberModel
{
    public static XdbModel Model { get; } = BuildModel();

    private static XdbModel BuildModel()
    {
        XdbModelBuilder modelBuilder =
            new XdbModelBuilder("MemberModel", new XdbModelVersion(1, 0));

        // Facets and events here
        modelBuilder.ReferenceModel(Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.CollectionModel.Model);

        modelBuilder.DefineFacet<Contact, MemberProfile>(MemberProfile.DefaultFacetKey);

        return modelBuilder.BuildModel();
    }
}
```

and I have serialized it and placed the .json file in `xConnect/Data`.

```
{
  "Name": "MemberModel",
  "Version": "1.0",
  "References": [
    {
      "Name": "XConnect",
      "Version": "1.0"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model",
      "Version": "9.0"
    }
  ],
  "Types": {
    "MemberProfile": {
      "Type": "Facet",
      "BaseType": "Sitecore.XConnect.Facet",
      "ClrType": "XXX.MemberProfile, ModelSerializer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
      "Properties": {
        "Zone": {
          "Type": "Int32"
        },
      }
    }
  },
  "Facets": [
    {
      "Target": "Contact",
      "Name": "MemberProfile",
      "Type": "MemberProfile"
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, in the `Sitecore.XConnect.Client.config` I have added:

```
  <schema name="membermodel" type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.StaticModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration">
      <param desc="modeltype">XXX.MemberModel, SEA.Models</param>
  </schema>
```

I have decompiled the `Sitecore.Analytics.Model` assembly to look at what is it doing when `Framework.ModelFactory.CreateFacet()` is called, and it basically tests if my custom facet, which inherits `Sitecore.XConnect.Facet`, is assignable from `Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework.IFacet`:

```
if (!typeof (IFacet).IsAssignableFrom(facetType))
    throw new ArgumentException("The specified type is not a valid facet type.", nameof (facetType));
```

I am obviously doing something wrong or missing something in a config file. I just can't find a solution. Any suggestion is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Just wanted to share some details here after this worked. The answer I accepted below helped me figure out how to patch the config, also that I needed to copy the json file to more than one folder. There is also another folder to copy the file into: /xconnect/jobs. At last I was able to store the data into the xdb_collection database:

[image: XConnect Data]

But I had the issue of not seeing the custom facet in-session, the data was only set to the database and read from there. So, to make it available in-session, I had to add the faced key to the Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config file:

```
<add name="xconnect" type="Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider, Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect">
  <facets hint="raw:AddFacet">
    <facet facetKey="Classification"/>
    <facet facetKey="MemberProfile"/>
  </facets>
  <GetOperationTimeout>0.00:00:05</GetOperationTimeout>
</add>
```

Comment: After doing all the four steps, will the custom facet be visible in the xDB or we will have to set some data in the custom facet only then it will be visible in the DB?

Comment: It should store data once you visit the site, unless you changed its default behavior. I got the tracker data in there plus my custom facet, even when browsing anonymously. You might need this to index the data and see it in the experience profile https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/enable-indexing-of-anonymous-contacts-in-the-xdb-index.html

Comment: Yes, you are right @freethinker6 when I created the contact added the in custom facet then data is visible in the xDB. But, I am not able to see the tracking detail in the experience profile for that contact, what am I missing for that? Even I added the facet key in the Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config for the session as you mentioned above.

Comment: @PrashantTomar I'd say you need to rebuild your index. Please take a look here https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/rebuilding-the-xdb-search-index.html ... also if you are working with anonymous contacts, you might want to index them https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/enable-indexing-of-anonymous-contacts-in-the-xdb-index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to perform the below steps to achieve this:

1. Create a Custom Facet Model
2. Register the Custom Facet Model
3. Deploy Custom Facet model to XDB
4. Add it to the `Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration`

**In step 3**, you need to place .JSON file at two places (You have placed it only one place):

```
x-connect root path > App_data/Models
x-connect root path > App_data/jobs/continuous/IndexWorker/App_data/Models
```

**In Step 4**, update your schema in `Sitecore.XConnect.Client.config` as below:

```
<schema name="membermodel" type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.StaticModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration" patch:after="schema[@name='collectionmodel']">
  <param desc="modeltype">XXX.MemberModel, SEA.Models</param>
```

You are missing **patch:after="schema[@name='collectionmodel']**

Please refer below both the blogs and verify if you missed anything.

[Create Custom Facet Model in Sitecore 9](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2019/06/create-custom-facet-model-in-sitecore-9.html)

[Work with Custom Facet in Sitecore 9](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2019/06/work-with-custom-facet-in-sitecore-9.html)

Let me know in case you need further help.

Comment: So, steps 1 to 4 are done as explained in the question. I have added the .json file to the locations mentioned. I have followed all the steps in your blog posts, but I still see the error message in the logs. I found this note in Sitecore.Analytics.Model.config: "In case you define custom facets and want GetFacet method to return an object of your custom facet type, make sure that data adapter provider (see sitecore/dataAdapterManager) supports your custom facet type." Any idea how to set that?

Comment: In Step 3 you need to place JSON file at two places.

Comment: Please see my first comment edited :)

Comment: Can you please confirm serialized JSON file is the same name as "MemberModel, 1.0.json"? please delete your serialized file and regenerate it again, as some time it gives "cannot create tracker error" when both custom facet model and serialized model are not same.

Comment: Added one more step in the answer for the config file 'Sitecore.XConnect.Client.config'.

Comment: so, I have serialized the model again, placed the files in the Model folders. Then patched as you said. Still getting the error. It is because Sitecore expects a different type of Facet, but I still don't figure out how to fix this. Does the name="membermodel" attribute mean something? Does it have to match the class name/facet key?

Comment: Please update your schema name in configuration file, it should be path of model class like I have "<schema name="SC.Analytics.Collection.Model" instead of membermodel.